# How to configure Windows Server & Desktop OS to use multiple Network Time (NTP) Servers?

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008, ntp

We experienced an outage in our usual NTP (Network Time Protocol) server - a Linux box that we sync all of our systems to.

I am noticing that in the "Adjust Date/Time -> Internet Time" tab I can set a single Internet Time Server entry.

Is there a way to configure Windows (Server 2008 R2 & 7 in our situation) to have multiple Time Server entries (similar to how we can configure multiple DNS servers) such that if the first one is not available, then it fails over to using the second entry?

Comment: Keep in mind that, when you specify multiple servers, then all the servers you specify will be used at the same time.  NTP will check the various servers against each other.  It doesn't simply switch when there is an outage.  The computers in your domain should sync only with the DCs, the DC should sync to several external servers.  (eg `pool.ntp.org`).

Answer (score 2):

Found my answer here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773263%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

From an elevated command prompt issue the w32tm command with the following switches:

> w32tm /config /update /manualpeerlist:"time.windows.com time.nist.gov"

You can check the status of the which peers the system is using and their update status by typing:

> w32tm /query /peers /verbose